# One piece chapters of manga

Tags: one-piece

What chapters will cover episodes 1-35 of anime of one piece manga?I want to skip the anime episodes and go straight to episode 36.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, the episode 35 ends near 77 in manga and you will have to read from 78 if you want to continue.

Source: https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_35